# Is the Flycam Galaxy Arm and Vest compatible with a Steadicam Solo?

Tags: video, video-recording, video-capture, stabilisation, composing

I am planning on getting myself a Steadicam Solo Stabilizer and Monopod from B&H Photo Video. However, for my purposes I would really need an arm and vest kit that I could mount it onto. While I saw that from B&H I could get the stabilizer with the Merlin arm and vest, but judging by reviews I think that the Flycam Galaxy Arm and Vest is higher in quality and more value for money. I definitely need an arm and vest, and I don't want to change my stabilizer, but I would simply like a yes or no answer: Is the Flycam Galaxy Arm and Vest compatible/can it fit onto and work with a Steadicam Solo, and if so, does it reduce performance as it is third party?

Thanks in advance.